# Android Eclipse - Buttons unfortunately changing upon click/touch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am constructing a calculator app, but I'm having a problem with the buttons.

It seems that the button text "jumps" up a bit on the surface of the button when it is clicked/touched. I have attached a before and after screenshot to show. Any ideas why this might be happening? I have attached my XML file on the bottom. If need be, I will attach my MainActivity.java as well if I see no assistance. Many thanks in advance.

[image: GUI pre-touch]

[image: GUI post-touch]

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#8CD11D"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.funkycalc.MainActivtiy\" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CLR"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="DEL"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/oneb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/twob"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/threeb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subtractb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fourb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fiveb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sixb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sevenb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eightb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nineb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divideb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zerob"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decimalb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="."
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiplyb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="x"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equalsb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="="
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"

    android:textSize="55sp" />
```

Comment: Each button that its text jumps add this line to it : `android:paddingTop="numpx"` num is how much PX you want that the text will get down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be better option if you use tablelayout throught out the layout rather than having Relative in i. Table Layout will keep it things organized in better way than relative. May be that would help

OR

try this with in every button:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: I've redone everything and started with a TableLayout and there is no button distortion, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with your [ninepatch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images

The following image from [this tutorial](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) could explain the cause of your problem
[image: ninepatch image setup]

The "fill area" is the area where the text is written. make sure your pressed-state images have the same fill area as the normal state ones.